# Uniform text wrapping in TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, textview

I need nice text wrapping in TextView, especially for text in headers.

Text wrapping for TextView might look like this, where the last word is in new line:

```
| ========================= |
|          =====            |
```

That what I would like to have is wrapping where lines width is more equable:

```
|     ================      |
|      ==============       |
```

It's easy to add '\n' for one language and test it on different screen sizes but not when there is more than 10 translations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified TextView and created UniformTextView. After investigating of TextView sources I have decided to minimize TextView's width to have preferred lines number.

```
    <pl.dziobas.uniformtextview.UniformTextView
        android:text="@string/sample_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:prefLineNumber="2"
        style="@style/sample_style" />
```

It works satisfactorily for me.
[image: UniformTextView example]

Sources are available on [github](https://github.com/dziobas/UniformTextView)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a '\n' in your string resouce xml to add a newline so you can managethe wrapping yourself.

Another approach would be to dynamically add the '\n' where you get the string length divided by 2 and search for the next space in either direction and on the first find you just add '\n' there. A hack, but probably work.

Other than that there is not much in Android for Hyphenation or Typography. Propably this post will give you some tips: http://smarter-than-the-average-pierre.blogspot.co.at/2011/10/bad-android-typography-tale-of-text.html

Comment: The problem is different translations and different screen sizes.

Comment: I know, thanks :). It works in small scale, not for 50 texts translated in 20 languages. I have no idea where to split the line in all languages :)

Comment: see my edit and try my hack, it probably work (if you have multi word headers)

Comment: I made a hack, but different one. Thanks for link to the article.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source project in **Github**  [AutoFittextView](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) and in **BitBucket** [AutoScaletextView](https://bitbucket.org/ankri/autoscaletextview/src).

***You can change according to your requirement.***

I tried the AutoScaleTextview and reached to the ***below OutPut***.

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for inspiration. Those libraries resizes text, I wanted to keep the text size.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm would be roughly:

1. calculate `String` width (with `Paint.measureText` or something)
2. if it is less than container (`TextView`) width, just use it
3. otherwise divide `String` width by container to know how many `"\n"` to enter
4. with some search algorithm look for a space character the closest to 1/nth of the width (again using `measureText` if the font is not monospace)
5. substring at that point and repeat point 4 for n-1 (n > 1)

Probably will require some adjustments like using container width by some small percent smaller than real.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I resize the `TextView` instead of putting new line. I don't know which solution is better. Greetings :)

Comment: @pawelzieba It works for you, so it is better. I guess it won't work with some layouts, which force width on their children. LinearLayout is liberal.

Answer (score 0):

If you know whats the text in advance (I means if its a hard coded text), you can fix the width of TextView in dp, so that it wraps up properly, or else you may also use android:ems to fix the maximum number of characters in a line. So your TextView can be:

```
<TextView
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:lines="2"/>
```

OR

```
  <TextView
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:ems="15"
     android:lines="2" />
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Android's own autoTextSizing for `TextView`, added in add API 26 with Support Library that supports from API 14 onwards with `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"`.

Have fun!

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html