# How to not make a new line textview if text is not full of textview width

Tags: android, textview

This is my TextView

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_ContentBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

1.When i set text 
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" 
or 
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"

2.My app is running and then it's show

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

or

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa-
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

I don't want it's to show like this.
(i think it's auto new line when " " or "-")

3.But I want it's to show like this (not new line if text not full of TextView)

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbb
```

or

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbb
```

How to set my TextView?

**EDIT**

I can solve it's by replace " " with Alt+0160 and replace "-" with Alt+0150

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to wrap text by chars? (Not by words)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118367/android-how-to-wrap-text-by-chars-not-by-words)

Comment: You can try modifying [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19759190/1777090)

Comment: Hey do you have specific code?

Comment: isnt Alt+0160 = u00A0? so the below answer should be correct: your_string.replace(" ", "\u00A0"); but this isn't working. How is yours working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

`your_string.replace(" ", "\u00A0");`

Then set the text to TextView

```
your_tv.setText(your_string);
```

Comment: thank you but it's work in case of " " not work in case of "-"

Comment: from you answer i can solve it's by replace " " with Alt+0160 and replace "-" with Alt+0150 thank you very much

Comment: @user2955394 Glad it helped you. You can upvote the answer too. Happy coding :)