# android resize chat bubbles width to wrapped text

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm trying to deal with nine patches and word wrapping inside a text view. The problem is that TextView doesn't resize its width to wrapped text, so the chat bubbles left a huge gap which I cannot reduce.

chat bubbles with gaps

[image]

Investigation of ViewHierarchy shows that these gaps are inside the TextView, view hierarchy of chat layout. so it's not related to the nine-patch.
[image]

May be somebody faced a similar issue...

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/messages"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/senderName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:gravity="bottom|start"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:textColor="@color/talkatone_gray"
    android:textSize="@dimen/chat_item_meta_info_text_size"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/chat_bubble_margin_top"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/form_chat_failed_to_open"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/chat_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/chat_text_message_size"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/attachment_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/chat_bubble_margin_top"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/video_play_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/play_gif"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: change linearlayout width to wrap_content the same for sender_name

Comment: @OussemaAroua applied your suggestion, thanks, but it obviously doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I think this is because the last word for the particular line cannot be fit in the space left on right, so it goes down. Try with smaller words and verify once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case the main problem is that you use it in adapter with viewholder pattern implementation.

So there is two issues you need to solve:

1. Reset TextView width each time before you'll reuse it.
2. Define longest line in your TextView measure and set appropriate width.

For reset TextView width add to your adapter getView() method, when you reuse your holder, next:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams paramsReset = holder.messageText.getLayoutParams();
paramsReset.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
holder.messageText.setLayoutParams(paramsReset);
```

For second issue you need to create custom view, extended from TextView and override onDraw() method:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(getLineCount() > 1)
    {
        float longestLineWidth = -1;
        for (int lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < getLineCount(); lineIndex++)
        {
            int lineStartIndex = getLayout().getLineStart(lineIndex);
            int lineEndIndex = getLayout().getLineEnd(lineIndex);
            String currentTextLine = getText().toString().substring(lineStartIndex, lineEndIndex);
            // Added "_____" for your paddings.
            float currentLineWidth = getPaint().measureText(currentTextLine + "_____");

            if (longestLineWidth < currentLineWidth)
            {
               longestLineWidth = currentLineWidth;
            }
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams paramsNew = getLayoutParams();
        paramsNew.width = (int) longestLineWidth;
        setLayoutParams(paramsNew);
    }
}
```

I override onDraw() also because of needed for use it in ListView, looks like you'll need to find other callback, that calls when holder has appeared in view.

---

It works, but not efficient, and have some other issues, please use it as first step.

Answer (score 0):

Use 9 patch images as background for your layout which allows you to create bitmap images that automatically resize to accommodate the contents of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your question also includes your answer:

> TextView doesn't resize its width to wrapped text

When you use `wrap_content` and allow multiple lines, the system will first grow the width of the `TextView` as wide as it can and only then start adding linebreaks. It never does a pass at the end to reclaim available width.

Of course, as with all things, you can solve this problem by writing your own custom `TextView` class. Here's a link to another project that attempted to solve a similar problem; maybe it will help give you ideas.

Other question: [Uniform text wrapping in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756126/uniform-text-wrapping-in-textview)

Custom TextView lib: https://github.com/dziobas/UniformTextView